# Android Emulator icon Does not show in Taskbar ,Why?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Android Emulator Icon in windows 7 does not show in TaskBar..see my Image...

[image]

I tried but cant get solution only this found http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21709

But cant Solve problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the link you posted it appears to be a known bug. Most likely the only solution is to wait for the next version of the ADK Tools to be released by Google.

But after all, it is just a missing icon and doesn't affect the ability to develop using the emulator.